# c# windows control that shows the downloading progress status of a file in a multithreaded software

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, status, download

So I whould like to develop a software in c# that will be capable of downloading youtube videos using threads.

Which control should i use in order to show the progress of each of the videos being downloaded in a given time?

Comment: Depends very much on you GUI framework.

Answer (score 2):

You can always use `ProgressBar` component in conjunction with `BackgroundWorker` to update the completion status.

Here is a basic sample: [C# Winform ProgressBar and BackgroundWorker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470927/c-winform-progressbar-and-backgroundworker)

By the way, a guy wrote a step-by-step instructions here which may be helpful: http://fernandof.wordpress.com/2007/04/04/implementing-multi-threading-in-winforms-using-the-backgroundworker-class/