# c# Progress Bar calling methods from another class

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar

I am trying to make a Progress Bar on a WinForm work by making two methods public and then calling the methods from another class (see my code example below).  But no luck, the bar does not move.

Here are the two classes:

```
namespace GP_Avantis_Integration
{
    //Class B
    public partial class GP_Avantis_Integration_Window : Form
    {
        public GP_Avantis_Integration_Window()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter sqlda = new SqlDataAdapter();
        SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand();

        public static int recno;

        public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                //Fetch data into memory

                //Fill in Header table

                //Fill in Line table

                //Cleaning open connection

                //Creating relationship in the Dataset between Header and Line table

                // Instantiating and Crearintg Header and Line source

                //Binding the Header source to the Header table

                //Binding the Line source to the relationship
            }

            catch (ApplicationException ae)
            {
            }

            finally
            {
            }
        }

        public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                //Calling CreateJE Class
                //Class Method ProcessData
                CreateJE JE = new CreateJE(); --------> Calls the Class B
                JE.ProcessData(ds);
                MessageBox.Show("Complete!");
            }

            catch (ApplicationException ae)
            {
            }

            finally
            {
            }
        }

        public void progress_Bar_setup()
        {
            progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
            progressBar1.Maximum = CreateJE.max;
        }

        public void progressBar_updates(int recno)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = recno;
            progressBar1.Update();
        }
    }

    // Class B
    class CreateJE
    {
        static public int max;
        public void ProcessData (DataSet ds)
        {
            //Create an eConnect Trx type object
            //POPTransactionType po = new POPTransactionType();

            // ***** PO Header and Line 

            int ln;
            ln = 0;

            //Setting up ProgressBar
            int recno = 1;
            max = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;

            GP_Avantis_Integration_Window w = new GP_Avantis_Integration_Window();
            w.progress_Bar_setup();

            // Create an eConnect PO Header node object

            // Create an array for lineitems

            foreach (DataRow dtrHDR in ds.Tables["Header"].Rows)
            {
                //ProgressBar Updates
                w.progressBar_updates(recno);

                //Instantiating GetJE object 
                //Retrieves the next JE from GP

                //Create an eConnect PO Header node object

                //Add the header node to the trx type object

                ln = 0;

                foreach (DataRow dtrLine in dtrHDR.GetChildRows("HdrLine"))
                {
                    // Populate the elements of the taPoLIne_ItemsTaPOLine XML node

                    //Avantis Inv Trx Key

                    // Avantis GL Trx Type

                    //Add POLine to an Array

                    ln ++;
                }

                // Add the header node to the trx type object

                // Add the lineitem node to the trx type object

                // ***** Process information only

                // Create an eConnect document object

                // Create a file on the HD

                // Serialize using the XmlTextWriter to the file

                // Call the eConnectMethods
                // Separate Class

                // Instantiating the object for eConnectMethods class
                // Passing last JRNENTRY retreived using the GetJE class
                // so if there is an error on the eConnectEntry Method of     eConnectMethods Class
                // I can pass the last JE number back to GP

                recno++;
            }  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What goes wrong? Does progessbar1.value change while debugging? If so you may need to kick off the foreach loop in a background thread.

Comment: You are not going to be able to call a property or method connect to Class B by using a reference to the progress bar. Post actual code, your example code, is not even valid code.  At this time unless you post code that can actually be compiled, you cannot be helped, please explain exactly what is not working.

Comment: I am setting min=0, max=2.  The value of 1 and 2 are being passed to the progressbar1.update() method with using foreach loop in class B.  When debugging I can see the values being passed.  The progressbar (visually) is not moving.

Comment: I presume that your somewhere you are showing your form?  The code you show above for class B declares a new instance of WinForm but it doesn't seem to call the Show method of that form.  Are you somehow passing the instance of class A into class B?  It seems that you are creating a new instance of WinForm in class B and trying to update that instance instead of your existing instance.  But the code you posted doesn't show that.  That's why it's important to show a short but complete program that can be compiled!

Comment: I included the full code with some edits.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what is the problem. May be the `max` value doesn't get initialized, may be the `update()` method doesn't redraw the progress bar.

One more thing: may be it's better to use the BackgroundWorker, so your UI won't lock? Here's an example: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/83317/BackgroundWorker-and-ProgressBar-demo

Comment: When debugging I am getting {value=1, min=0, max=2} values on the progressbar1.update().  So it seems like the values are being passed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to invoke the updating with render priority, like this:

```
 public void progressbar_updates(int recno)
 {
     Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
     {
              progressbar1.Value += recno;
              progressbar1.UpdateLayout();
     }), DispatcherPriority.Render);
 }
```

Comment: Dispatcher is WPF. OP said he's using WinForms.

Answer (score 0):

Implement a backgroundWorker and use `backgroundworker.ReportProgress` to update the progressbar. It will then implement your code in one thread and the UI in another thead. Then the form will be responding to updates. Just be cautious when you read and write to the UI (because it is in another thead) Read the UI over when you start the Backgroundworker and write in ReportProgress.

[C# Winform ProgressBar and BackgroundWorker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470927/c-sharp-winform-progressbar-and-backgroundworker)

Answer (score 0):

Use backgrounworker.
This is the best example
[Click here for BackGroundWorker](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/BackgroundWorker_Threads.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a "Worker Form" which displays progress of background tasks.

Here's my code (WorkerForm)

```
        #region Form
    private void frmLoader_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
                    if (OnExecute != null)
        {
            OnExecute(this, null);
        }
    }
    #endregion
    #region "Public"
    public void OnInitialize(object sender, EventArgs<String, int> e)
{
  if (pbLoader.InvokeRequired)
  {
    pbLoader.Invoke(new Action<object, EventArgs<String, int>>(OnInitialize), new Object[] { sender, e });
  }
  else
  {
    lblDynamicText.Text = e.Param1;
    pbLoader.Step = 1;
    pbLoader.Minimum = 1;
    pbLoader.Value = 1;
    pbLoader.Maximum = e.Param2;
  }
}
public void OnCreate(object sender, EventArgs<String> e)
{
  if (lblDynamicText.InvokeRequired)
  {
    lblDynamicText.Invoke(new Action<object, EventArgs<String>>(OnCreate), new Object[] { sender, e });
  }
  else
  {
    lblDynamicText.Text = e.Param1;
    pbLoader.PerformStep();
  }
}
public void OnFinished(object sender, EventArgs<String> e)
{
  if (lblDynamicText.InvokeRequired)
  {
    lblDynamicText.Invoke(new Action<object, EventArgs<String>>(OnFinished), new Object[] { sender, e });
  }
  else
  {
    lblDynamicText.Text = e.Param1;
  }
}
```

In my presenter (I'm using a ModelViewPresenter architecture) I inject both a reference to the Winform and the actual worker class.

```
 internal WorkerPresenter(IWorkerView WorkerView,IWorker ConcreteWorker)
{
  this.WorkerView = WorkerView;
  this.ConcreteWorker = ConcreteWorker;
  WorkerView.OnExecute += StartExecute;
}
```

StartExecute is being raised during the Form Load Event of my Worker Form.

```
private void StartExecute(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ConcreteWorker.OnCreate += Create;
  ConcreteWorker.OnFinish += Finished;
  ConcreteWorker.OnInitialize += Initialize;
    var task = new Task<bool>(ConcreteWorker.Execute);
    task.Start();
    task.ContinueWith(c_task =>
    {
      ((frmWorker)WorkerView).DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
    });
}
```

IWorker interface:

```
  public interface IWorker  {
event EventHandler<EventArgs<String>> OnCreate;
event EventHandler<EventArgs<String>> OnFinish;
event EventHandler<EventArgs<String, int>> OnInitialize;
bool Execute();
```

}

Concrete Worker: OnInitialize => Set a text and the amount of steps in your progress bar. OnCreate => Increments the step counter by one and sets another text. 
OnFinish => displays a text and closes the Worker form again.